# CakePdf not reading CSS

Tags: css, cakephp

The **CakePdf** Plugin (CakePdf.**DomPdf**) is not reading my stylesheet for some reason.. My **/View/Layouts/pdf/default.ctp** is the same as my /View/Layouts/default.ctp that works fine on the other pages. How come this is not recognized on the pdf? Is it because it's inside another directory? If so, it's not giving any error. It downloads the pdf as it should but the file has not style. What is going on? Is there something else I need to change?

Comment: Look at your layout source in the browser locate the css and click it to see if it exists or not or debug in chrome developer tools to see if the css returns 200 OK. CakePHP does not throw an error for missing css files.

Comment: The css is obviously not read since it's not styled but I don't know how to correct it: whether I need to change how I called it echo $this->fetch('css'); or echo $this->Html->css('/css/style.css'); .. Or whether it has something to do with how cake works since it's no longer under View/Layouts/ but under View/Layouts/pdf/ .. Or whether it's changed by the cakePdf plugin .. @woodscreative

Comment: Another thing is that since it is displayed as /Controller/parameter.pdf, the CakePdf plugin is displaying it via embed tag <embed width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" src="http://...parameter.pdf" type="application/pdf">.. So, I can't see the html source at all or the css @woodscreative

Comment: So, Leah, how did you solve this? I can't see the syle either and I'm sure the path is full based

Comment: as far as I can see, full base is not the only matter.
there are other DomPDF options which may be of interest, such as isRemoteEnabled, and isHtml5ParserEnabled

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue I faced also.

To solve this, you need to edit your AppHelper in app/View/Helper and include the assetUrl code I give below. What it do is it will set the fullbase to true if the extension of file is pdf. This should fix your issue.

```
public function assetUrl($path, $options = array()) {
        if (!empty($this->request->params['ext']) && $this->request->params['ext'] === 'pdf' ) {
            $options['fullBase'] = true;
        }
        return parent::assetUrl($path, $options);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using:

```
<?= $this->Html->css(WWW_ROOT . '/css/pdf.css') ?>
```

works for me.